# Why does VI ii°7 V7 i sound so bad in minor?

Tags: voice-leading

[image]

I am currently working on subdominant 7th chords. In some exercises I'm asked to voice lead typical subdominant to dominant progressions. Most the progressions I'm asked to write are in major. I'm trying to do some in minor just to get a different idea of what it sounds like and I came up with this progression which is supposed to be very standard chord progression but for some reason it doesn't sound very good. Or at least not as good as in major. I don't know why because the voice leading seems okay. Is it the dissonant interval in the bass line that makes it sound not as good as it does in major? Was this chord progression used in classical harmony at all or was ii65 the go to chord?

the progression in my image is in c#

Comment: You have full diminished seventh in the title but half dim in the score, and I think you meant `B` natural, not sharp, in the score.

Comment: Key signature and clefs would help

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - quoted C#minor thus G and F clefs. And leading note should be B# in that cey.

Comment: @Tim It would be much more clear to have the clef and sharps next to the clef written out in the score.

Answer (score 4):

There are two "rules" broken in the given progression:

1. No leaps by tritone;
2. No leaps into a dissonance.

The reason these rules came into being is exactly what you've discovered: they create harsh(er) sounds.

The bass's leap from `A` to `D#` is itself harsh sounding (within the aesthetic expectations of tonal theory), and the `D#` is dissonant against the `A` in the `ii7` chord.

The difference with using `ii65` is that the bass makes a consonant leap from the `VI` chord's `A` to the `ii` chord's `F#`, and there are no dissonances in the `ii` chord against the `F#`: there are a minor sixth, a minor third, and a perfect fifth.

Comment: "Classical music" encompasses quite a lot of music. Off the top of my head, I don't know an example of root-position ii7 - V in. minor, but I'll update if/when I stumble onto one.

Comment: So was this chord progression not used in minor at all? according to some of my books ii°7 was used a lot so how was it approached? From scale degree 6 then is a no-no according to what you say and this is the sxale degree that most often precedes a ii chord.

Comment: @armani Another “solution” might be III instead of VI or between VI and ii

Comment: did you mean to say: no dissonances in the ii65 chord?

Comment: Todd III to ii°7 you think will work?

Comment: I assume this has a key sig of three flats for C minor. Did you mean `A` flat to `D` natural?

Comment: @armani I didn't say it wasn't used; only that out of the hundreds of thousands of classical pieces, I didn't happen to automatically know of a specific example. And, no, I didn't claim there are no dissonances in the ii65 chord. There are no dissonances between the bass and any other individual voice.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Key specified in the OP is C# minor.

Comment: Ah, I totally missed that.

Comment: @armani, if you want to avoid these dissonances, just arpeggiate the bass from the `A` up to `E` before it moves to `D#`.

Comment: Michael, in real world composition I will keep that tip in mind thanks!